# Could not load System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity.dll (Yet it's there)

Tags: c#, silverlight, ria, sql-server-ce-4

I have a silverlight application. The server app has an SQL Server CE 4 .sdf in App_Data, and an ADO.NET model generated from it.

If I try to Add->New Item->Domain Service Class, I get the error:

> Schema specified is not valid. Errors:
>   Models.TasksDatabaseMode.ssdl(2,98): error (0004): Could not load
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity.dll. Reinstall SQL Server Compact.

However, I installed RIAServices.EntityFramework and EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact via NuGet, which has successfully downloaded this .dll to /packages, and the file has been copied out into the /bin folder. So I have no idea where it is apparently looking for this .dll, if not there.

Perhaps related, I was earlier attempting to have the database generated code-first. However, the Domain Context Wizard was also failing, but with an error about an index being out of bounds. With a manually written service, the build was failing with a MetadataWorkspace error, about which I couldn't find any information.

Answer (score 0):

Does installing the runtime directly (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876) fix the issue?

Also, what version of the binary are you using?  I suspect that you may have the private version (4.0.0.1) and generation is expecting the machine version (4.0.0.0)